# Projection of data onto principal component yields incorrect result

Tags: python, numpy, plot, data-visualization, linear-algebra

I'm attempting to project 2D data points onto the top principal component of the data's covariance matrix, but my projected points don't lie on the expected vector. Below is my code and output. I've looked at other questions asked and still can't determine what might be the problem. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or spot the error?

```
# generate random 2D data (2 neurons, 40 data points each)
t = 40
r1 = [i for i in range(40)]
r2 = [i+np.random.randint(-20,20) for i in range(40)]
data = np.array([r1,r2]) / 10

# SVD
data_cov = data @ data.T # covariance matrix (<x,x.T>)
u, s, v = np.linalg.svd(data_cov, full_matrices=True) # svd
dir_max_var = v[:,0] # direction of maximal variance

# project data
data_proj = np.ndarray(shape=(2,t))
v_norm = np.sqrt(sum(dir_max_var**2)) 
for i in range(t):
    data_proj[:,i] = ((data[:,i] @ dir_max_var)/v_norm**2)*dir_max_var

# # project data - vectorized (gives same output as the for loop version)
# data_T = data.T # (40 x 2) * (2 x 1) * (1 x 2) = 
# data_proj = data_T @ dir_max_var.reshape(1,2).T @ dir_max_var.reshape(1,2)
# data_proj = data_proj.T


# plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
ax.scatter(data[0,:],data[1,:], s=75, c='gray', edgecolors='w')
ax.scatter(data_proj[0,:],data_proj[1,:], s=100,alpha=0.2,c='red', edgecolors='w')
ax.set_xlabel('$r_1$')
ax.set_ylabel('$r_2$')
ax.quiver(np.mean(data[0,:]),np.mean(data[1,:]),dir_max_var[0],dir_max_var[1], \
          color='green',scale=1, alpha = 0.6)
ax.quiver(np.mean(data[0,:]),np.mean(data[1,:]),-dir_max_var[0],-dir_max_var[1], \
          color='green',scale=1, alpha = 0.6)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the axes for all the separate plots were different. Using `plt.axis('equal')` corrects the issue.